# for loop does not iterate until the last item

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, return

I have a problem with this function

```
def morethan120(list1):
    n = 0
    y = pd.to_datetime("0:00:00")
    for i in list1:
        if y < pd.to_datetime("2:00:00"):
            z = y
            y = y + i
            n = n + 1
        else:
            n = n - 1
            print(n)
            print(z)
            return

for m in late120_list:
    lateid = time_table[time_table["AC-No."] == m]
    lateid = lateid[lateid["Late"].notnull()]
    print(m)
    morethan120(lateid["Late"])
```

I don't understand why `m` iterates till the end. It's just stops and does not `print(n)` or `print(z)` as it did for the rest of the list.

this is the result

```
5 # m value
4 # n value
2016-11-30 01:49:00 # z value
6 # m value
8 # n value
2016-11-30 01:50:00 # z value
7
0
2016-11-30 00:00:00
10 # m value and it stop at here
```

the basis of this code is to get the time-stamp before it reach 2:00:00 and get the index of that time-stamp

this is lateid dataframe

```
     AC-No.     Late
97       5 00:10:00
98       5 00:16:00
99       5 00:04:00
100      6 00:08:00
101      6 00:10:00
102      6 00:13:00
105      7 00:35:00
106      7 00:22:00
107      10 00:38:00
```

this is late120_list

```
[5, 6, 7, 10]
```

Comment: Seems like for the last iteration, the `else` case is never executed until the loop finishes normally.

Comment: What do you mean by that? And how to change it?